# Handling "OK" button from UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c

I have an alert view set up for two names to be entered like so

UITextField *player1;
        UITextField *player2;

```
    UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter 2 player names"
                                                     message:@"\n\n\n" // IMPORTANT
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];

    player1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 25)];
    [player1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [player1 setPlaceholder:@"player1"];
    [prompt addSubview:player1];

    player2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 85, 260, 25)];
    [player2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [player2 setPlaceholder:@"player2"];
    [prompt addSubview:player2];

    // set place
    [prompt setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 110)];
    [prompt show];
    //[prompt release];

    // set cursor and show keyboard
    [player1 becomeFirstResponder];
```

Now I would like to handle the "OK" button click.  I'm attempting to do something like this with no luck..

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"cancel");
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK works" message:@"no error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
}
```

From what I've read this should work.  However when I press the 'ok' button nothing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `self` for delegate for the `UIAlertView`.

```
UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter 2 player names"
                                                     message:@"\n\n\n" // IMPORTANT
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Comment: Well...I can't accept an answer for another 12 minutes.  Thanks!

Comment: What would be the best way to get the text from both of the field within the alertView method?

Comment: @joshft91 you can assign tag to textfield and and then from tag get textfield and  its value..

Comment: @Bhargavi there's a certain time after the question has been asked before an answer can be accepted.

Comment: @Bhargavi Could you give me a few more details as to what you mean to assign tag to textfield and then get the textfield & its value?

Comment: @joshft91 as you have globally defined your textfields then you can directly use it.

Comment: I thought I had tried that before...apparently I was doing it wrong.  Thanks again.

Comment: @joshft91 please look at the answer posted.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** *Not related original question but as per comment "Could you give me a few more details as to what you mean to assign tag to textfield and then get the textfield & its value? " I am posting answer here.*

Assign tags to textfields

```
    UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter 2 player names"
                                                     message:@"\n\n\n" // IMPORTANT
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];

    player1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 25)];
    [player1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [player1 setPlaceholder:@"player1"];
    [player1 setTag:100]; // added this
    [prompt addSubview:player1];

    player2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 85, 260, 25)];
    [player2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [player2 setPlaceholder:@"player2"];
    [player2 setTag:200]; // added this
    [prompt addSubview:player2];

    // set place
    [prompt setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 110)];
    [prompt show];
    //[prompt release];

    // set cursor and show keyboard
    [player1 becomeFirstResponder];
```

Retrieving value

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"cancel");
        }
        else
        {
            UITextField *txtPlayer1 = (UITextField*)[alertView viewWithTag:100];
            NSLog(@"Value for player1: %@",txtPlayer1.text);

            UITextField *txtPlayer2 = (UITextField*)[alertView viewWithTag:200];
            NSLog(@"Value for player2: %@",txtPlayer2.text);

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK works" message:@"no error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to check the button index of the alertview.

as stated setting delegate to self too when showing the UIAlertview, then...

```
    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"index 0 pressed ie cancel button");
        // do something when cancel pressed
    }
    else NSLog(@"index 1 pressed ie ok button");
         // do something when ok button pressed
}
```